# Change negative sign into parentheses pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I am attempting to change negative numbers in a DataFrame into an accounting format. The goal is to change numbers that look like this: `$-1123.12` into numbers that look like this: `($1123.12)`.

The DataFrame has the form:

```
index  col A    col B   col C
0      $11.12  $7.34    66.6%
1      $-9.32  $-2.33   25.0%
2      $0.37   $0.21    56.0%
3      $32.10  $3.21    10.0%
```

I would like for my data frame to have the form:

```
index  col A    col B   col C
0      $11.12  $7.34    66.6%
1      ($9.32) ($2.33)  25.0%
2      $0.37   $0.21    56.0%
3      $32.10  $3.21    10.0%
```

My attempted solution went through each column of my DataFrame using a for loop to see if any columns contained the pattern: `$-`. If the columns contained said pattern, my goal was to replace said pattern with `($` and terminate the newly formed string with `)`.

The solution appears as follows:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].astype('string').str.contains(pat = "$-", regex = True):
       df[col] = df[col].astype('string').str.replace("$-", "($") + ")"
    else:
       df[col] = df[col]
    return df[col]
```

However, when I ran this solution I got the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Edit:
I have overlooked a very important detail. Numbers above 999.99, have commas. For example:

`$1,123.12`

I am attempted to get them to this form:

`($1,123.12)`

Please ask additional questions if you have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the pattern and reconstruct the output with [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) dataframe wise with following regex:

- Match pattern: `\$-([0-9.]+)` captures the negative number
- Replace pattern: `($\1)` refers to captured number with `\1` and wrap it in parenthesis.

---

```
df.replace(r'\$-([0-9.]+)', r'($\1)', regex=True)

   index    col A    col B  col C
0      0   $11.12    $7.34  66.6%
1      1  ($9.32)  ($2.33)  25.0%
2      2    $0.37    $0.21  56.0%
3      3   $32.10    $3.21  10.0%
```

Comment: This solution did work for the most part. However, I've neglected to say that my numbers actually have the form `$-123,123.12`.  Your solution gives the following: `($123),123.12`. The commas unfortunately distort the solution, and it seems as though the parentheses stop when they meet the first comma. How does one incorporate both the commas, as well as the decimal places?

Comment: Hmm why do you want to incorporate the other number since it's not negative ?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I've done a poor job of explaining what I'm trying to do. I have a number `-123123.12`. I have managed to change it to the form `-$123,123.12`. I would like it in the form `($123,123.12)`. This is all one number, not two. Please feel free to ask any additional questions.

Comment: Basically, I have commas on the thousands place, and would like to incorporate those on larger numbers.

Comment: In that case, you can just add comma to the match pattern: `\$-([0-9.,]+)`, since we want to treat comma as valid in a number here.